# How to duplicate lines in Linux with keeping the original order?

Tags: linux

I have a file (with only 1 column) like this:

```
A
B
Z
D
N
```

and what I want to do is to duplicate each line so I get this:

```
A
A
B
B
Z
Z
D
D
N
N
```

I only could think of using cat for the same file and then sort it:

```
cat file1 file1 | sort -k1 > file1_duplicate
```

but then I lose the order of my file which is important for me:

```
A
A
B
B
D
D
N
N
Z
Z
```

any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try e.g.

```
sed p file >newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1;}{print $1;}' file.txt > duplicatefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

LSB has perl5. This will do the trick:

```
cat file1 |  perl -pe '$_.=$_' > file1_duplicate
```

Comment: You could simply `print` a second time from inside Perl, just like I demonstrate in `sed`.  Also, that's a Useless Use of Cat.  http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @tripleee Indeed there are more than one way to do this in perl. using cat, fil1 and file1_duplicate was taken from the question. It won't be much worse performance wise and if you need somethng more, eg. pv in between, you don't need to change it :)

Comment: Oh, I just thought it looked too cryptic. But the needless string copy is easy to avoid, too.

Answer (score 0):

With `coreutils` `paste` you can do it like this:

```
paste -d'\n' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | tail --lines=1 >> file
```